# setting static member variable inside a static method

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-members

I am beginner to C++ and have a doubt about static member variables and member functions.

I have implemented a class as follows -

```
class Foo
{
private:
    static int myVariable;
public:
    static void setMyVariable()
    {
        myVariable = 100;
    }

    static void resetMyVariable()
    {
        myVariable = 0;
    }
};
```

There are following considerations when I wrote a code like that -

- I want only one instance of class Foo. Thats why I made all member variables and functions as static.
- I don't want the outside code to touch `myVariable`

I have put this class in a header file and included in my main file. When I do this, I get an error `undefined reference to Foo::myVariable`

I want to know if I can write a code which can satisfy above requirements?

Thanks !

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/1782465).

Comment: If you only want one instance you should take a look at the singleton pattern (now flame me haters ;) )

Comment: You want a set of free functions and a static global variable in a separate C++ file, neither a singleton or a class with only static members

Comment: Singletons can be an evil thing. But if he wants only one instance of the class, then he probably wants non-static member variables with a Singleton pattern in preference to a whole batch of static stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define static class variables *somewhere*:
e.g. in your main C++ file,

```
int Foo::myVariable;
```

Note that technically, by making everything static, you may have no *instances* of `Foo`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I understood now what you mean and with other previous comments. Since now I have to define this variable in main, does it mean that it is exposed outside and no longer private.

Comment: @Raj No, it's not exposed. Access control still applies when referring to the variable.